# sed replace exact string that include brackets

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, word-boundary

i'm trying to replace an exact string that includes bracket on it. let's say:
a[aa] to bbb, just for giving an example.

I had used the following regex:

```
sed  's|\<a\[aa]\>|bbb|g' testfile
```

but it doesn't seem to work. this could be something really basic but I have not been able to make it work so I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You may try `sed  's|\<a\[aa]|bbb|g' testfile`, the right word boundary requires a letter, digit or `_` to follow the `]` char.

Comment: sorry, my regex is wrong, i have tried something like sed -i "s|\<a\[aa\]\>|bb|g" testfile

Comment: yeah, i read that  ] should not be escaped, but even in that way it doesn't work

Comment: See https://ideone.com/RQVwaK

Comment: So, is there a way of having a word boundary with this kind of strings?

Comment: in my case, this is just part of a line, and i would like to replace only the a[aa] part, and not the whole line

Comment: But what is your definition of the right-hand boundary? Do you mean there must be whitespace or end of string?

Comment: there must be a whitespace

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Show the strings you want to match **in context** surrounded by similar strings that you do **not** want to match as that's the hard part of your question. See also [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) as that matter is the string you want to match can contain RE metachars or sed regexp delimiter chars. Also tell us which sed version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the trailing word boundary that requires a letter, digit or `_` to immediately follow the `]` char.

```
sed 's|\<a\[aa]|bbb|g' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/RQVwaK):

```
s="say: a[aa] to bbb, not ba[aa]"
sed 's|\<a\[aa]|bbb|g' <<< "$s"
# => say: bbb to bbb, not ba[aa]
```

You may also **require a non-word char** with a capturing group and replace with a backreference:

```
sed -E 's~([^_[:alnum:]]|^)a\[aa]([^_[:alnum:]]|$)~\1bbb\2~g' file
```

Here, `([^_[:alnum:]]|^)` captures any non-word char or start of string into Group 1 and `([^_[:alnum:]]|$)` matches and caprures into Group 2 any char other than `_`, digit or letter, and the `\1` and `\2` placeholders restore these values in the result. This, however, does not allow consecutive matches, so you may still use `\<` before `a` to play it safe: `sed -E 's~\<a\[aa]([^_[:alnum:]]|$)~bbb\1~g'`. file`.

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/0e0zf9).

To enforce **whitespace boundaries** you may use

```
sed -E 's~([[:space:]]|^)a\[aa]([[:space:]]|$)~\1bbb\2~g' file
```

Or, in your case, just a trailing whitespace boundary seems to be enough:

```
sed -E 's~\<a\[aa]([[:space:]]|$)~bbb\1~g' file
```

Comment: is there a way to do a boundary with this kind of string without adding anything before the ] ?

Comment: @dperezg Please explain what you mean by either explicit verbal rules or a couple of sample strings with expected outputs.

Comment: @dperezg Updated with all sorts of common "word" boundaries.